# Foundation grid layout not preserved when using Slick to create carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm creating a page that needs to have 4 carousel slides and I decided to use slick. Each of the 4 slide is a div of foundation class "row" . Inside each of these rows, I have two columns, the first one contains a h4 and has width 3 on medium screen, and the second column contains an image and is of width 6 on medium screen. Both these columns are centered inside the row. Here is what my carousel section looks like:

```
<section id="projects" class="row full-width align-center">

    <div class="columns small-11 align-middle carousel">

        <div class="row full-width align-center align-middle">
            <div class="columns small-12 medium-3 large-3">
                <h4 class="centered uppercased section-title">Human and Robot</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="columns small-12 medium-6 large-6 left">
                <img src="data/pics/robot.gif" alt="robot">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row full-width align-center align-middle">
            <div class="columns small-12 medium-3 large-3">
                <h4 class="centered uppercased section-title">Mini-skype</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="columns small-12 medium-6 large-6 left">
                <img src="data/pics/skype_info.png" alt="skype">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row full-width align-center align-middle">
            <div class="columns small-12 medium-3 large-3">
                <h4 class="centered uppercased section-title">Portfolio</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="columns small-12 medium-6 large-6 left">
                <img src="data/pics/svn.jpg" alt="portfolio">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row full-width align-center align-middle">
            <div class="columns small-12 medium-3 large-3">
                <h4 class="centered uppercased section-title">Chess</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="columns small-12 medium-6 large-6 left">
                <img src="data/pics/chess.png" alt="chess">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

Before applying Slick carousel effect, each of the carousel looks like this(this is the desired layout):

[image]

However, after calling the slick function in my js file :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".carousel").slick({
        dots: true,
        speed: 300
    });
});
```

It's able to achieve the carousel effect, but the layout of the row is no longer preserved and the two columns get stacked on each other like this:
[image]

What should I do to get Slick to work friendly with Foundation ? I know one way is to modify the slick.css or slick.js but for some reason I'm not allowed to do this (the slick library will be re-installed everytime I deployed the page). I also tries adding a varaibleWidth: true to the setting but that simply disables the carousel effect. Have any of you encountered this problem before and how did you solve it?

Comment: Which version of Foundation are you using?